# jQuery vertical autoscroll not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get text in a div to vertically autoscroll (at one speed) and pause when the user hovers their cursor over it but can't seem to get my code working. How can I go about achieving this? This is my code so far:

JavaScript

```
$('#scroll').children().animate({'margin-top': '-=' + ($('#scroll').children().height()-100)}, 10000);
```

HTML

```
<div id="scroll">Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here<br />
        <br />
        Content here and more content here </div>​
```

​In addition, I've also uploaded my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/5DmZh/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more cost effective approach would be to place another wrapper inside `#scroll` and animate that instead of trying to position every child element.

Check out my code at **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KjX8/73/)**, though I guess you want the animation to loop forever.

Comment: +1 for the nice solution, I was also trying to do something like this.